# RecyclerView items change size after refresh

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` as the following image presents:

[image: RecyclerView]

This is the setup code for this `RecyclerView`:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
dataRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
dataRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(...);
dataRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

after starting a new activity where I update the selected item of the RecyclerView, the RecyclerView is re-populated with new data to reflect the new change, but I get the following result:

[image: Result 1]

And when I scroll down, I get this gap:

[image: Result 2]

I tried calling `RecyclerView#invalidate()`, `#invalidateItemDecorations()`, `#requestLayout()` after the refresh but to no avail; & I'm also not calling `setHasFixedSize(true)` on the `RecyclerView`.

What is the problem exactly ? How can I resize the child items so as they wrap their content precisely after refreshing?

*(P.S: I tried refreshing without making any changes & nothing happened, which proves my theory that the issue arises only when a child item's height changes.)*

Comment: share your code of adapter

Comment: post your adapter and xml code for adapter...

Comment: The code of the adapter is a bit long, it is extending a few generic classes. But the binding process is very normal.

Comment: I have faced with same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Nik unfortunately, I never did.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZouag can you resolve this problem if yes then how?

Comment: @MohammedAoufZouag have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

That's quite late but I have also experienced this problem. This could be helpful for those still having the same bug.

In my case the solution was checking if there are any item decoration for recyclerview:

`recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(8));`

This line was called everytime recyclerview is updated and was make recyclerview items getting smaller. Hope it helps the other.

Happy Coding,
Baki

Comment: Thank you for your "late" suggestion haha, I am in no position to try this fix at the moment, but I will certainly keep it in mind. Thanks !